# How do i get effect when gems come together in godot?

Tags: godot

I'm create gems puzzle game, In my game there is requirement that 2x2 matrix gem will group and then it will convert in power gem. check below image.

[image]

I'm new in game development, so anyone can point me out ? any suggestion or link will be helpfull.

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you have a problem with doing this? Is it detecting that the small gems are in this formation? Is it with removing them and replacing them with a big gem? Is it with determining the properties of the big gem? Please be specific.

Comment: @Philipp I want to replace 4 gems with big gem? for than i need to add another image? or it can be done without it?

Comment: Your example clearly shows that the big gem image has details which aren't in the small gem image, so the example would require two separate images. But if the small gems and large gems actually look the same, you can use the same image and just double the scale in the Transform of the Node2D.